# How to iterate in an ArrayList and retrieve a particular data type value?

Tags: java, arraylist

The problem I have is with the raw use of the array list. I want to find an object with a given specific type. How can I do that?

Here is the sample code I have.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList nameList =  new ArrayList();
        
         nameList.add(0,"OREO");
         nameList.add(1,100);
         nameList.add(2," d");
         nameList.set(0, "sammy");
         
         for(int i=0; i>nameList.size();i++){
             
             
             if(nameList.get(i).getClass()=String.class){ /*Run time error*/
                 // values are in the arraylist
                 //i want to iterate the arraylist and retrieve values that are of datatype String only. later for integer/double etc...
                 //after iterate i will have have a new arraylist having the retrieved values(new values).
                  System.out.println(nameList);
             }
         }
        
    }
```

Comment: You're looking for the `instanceof` operator. Though why you would be keeping a list of `Object` isn't quite apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code to use `instanceof` operator. Here is a sample code using a for each loop:

```
for(Object object: nameList){                    
             if(object instanceof Double) {
              //Do logic here.
             }
         }
```

Overall the raw use of ArrayList is not recommended. You can replace the raw use with a list of objects such as:  `List<Object>`

Comment: what is happening in this code. IS IT of what i understood //for an object in the arraylist, if that object is of datatype Integer, return 1 else -1 ???

Answer (score 0):

Use the foreach method with lambda as consumer action

```
 nameList.forEach(e-> {
        if (e instanceof String) System.out.println(e);
    });
```